# Having Trouble Learning to Make QR Scanner for Swift 4 Xcode 10

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

Hello fellow programmers, I'm having trouble making a QR Scanner on the iPhone. When I run the code below, the camera is up and running but will not scan a QR code when pointing at one. A function should be called with the decoded string as an argument once it sees and deciphers the QR.  The code file is linked to an empty view on the storyboard. Here is the code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import AVFoundation

class ScannerViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

    var intendedDest = String()

    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

        guard let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
        let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput

        do {
            videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
        } catch {
            return
        }

        if (captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)) {
            captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
        } else {
            failed()
            return
        }

        let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

        if (captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
            captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

            metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive))
            metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.ean8, .ean13, .pdf417]
        } else {
            failed()
            return
        }

        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)

        captureSession.startRunning()
    }

    func failed() {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Scanning not supported", message: "Your device does not support scanning a code from an item. Please use a device with a camera.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
        captureSession = nil
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if (captureSession?.isRunning == false) {
            captureSession.startRunning()
        }
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        if (captureSession?.isRunning == true) {
            captureSession.stopRunning()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection){
        captureSession.stopRunning()

        if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {
            guard let readableObject = metadataObject as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject else { return }
            guard let stringValue = readableObject.stringValue else { return }
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
            found(code: stringValue)
        }

        dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    func found(code: String) {  
        // qr code found!   
        print(code)           
    }    
}
```

Comment: What is going wrong does the function found is being called  ?

Comment: You are not adding .qr to the following.  metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.ean8, .ean13, .pdf417]

Comment: Is it resolved @AryanPatel ?

Comment: @Dili yes the problem is now resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As El Tomato suggested, adding `.qr` to your array of metadataObjectTypes will allow the app to scan QR codes. [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmetadatamachinereadablecodeobject/machine-readable_object_types) is a link to documentation of various code types.

Comment: I did not catch that... i do not have a testing device with me at the moment. I will try adding it and seeing if it works later. :)